# Unity 3D vs openGL

Tags: c++, unity

i'm interrested in starting to learn abit about graphics programming through game development and i'm wondering what the pros/cons are when using Unity 3D over using something like C++ & openGL

Answer (score 6):

asking Unity3D vs. C++ & OpenGL is like asking whether to buy a Car vs. or a Wheel. You either know how to build a car using it's parts or you need to use already built cars out there!

Answer (score 0):

Unity 3D is an integrated development environment for game development.
C++ and openGL are just tools you can use for game production.

It's hard to compare them because of that.
For starters I'd suggest you finding a 2D game library for your favourite language and only then switching to c++ / openGL when you feel ready.

Comment: Okay thanks, well i've programmed for 1-2 years in C++ but i wanna start getting into graphical programming and i'm interested in doing a game ^^